# Check if external accessory is in 30-pin dock connector programmatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uidevice, external-accessory

I've found answers on how to check if the iPhone is being charged, and at what level it is at. But what about just checking if the dock connector is being used up by any external accessory (including the charger), or whatever it may be. I couldn't find any way how to in the UIDevice class reference.

Comment: @user762034: Did you got the solution ? If so please suggest me too.

Answer (score 0):

I do believe there is an accessory detect pin on the 30 pin dock connector.  From what I have read hooking the pin to ground and putting different resistors on the dock connector makes the iPhone think it is a certain device.  You might want to check out this http://pinoutsguide.com/PortableDevices/ipod_pinout.shtml

Comment: How can I detect whether the external accessory connected is 30 pin or audio jack programaically? Any suggestion?